# Is there a way to carry a variable/bool up and into a View's SuperView?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Say I were to have the follow sudocode as a View named Item

```
Item{
  Rectangle()
   .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
   .onTapGesture{
     isTapped.toggle()
   }
}
```

And there were multiple Items in it's superview, *Content*

```
Content{
  VStack{
    Item()
    Item()
    Item()
  }
}
```

Would there be a way for me to relay the variable/bool *isTapped* from Item, up and into it's superview with it still being Item specific? (So I know which Item has what *isTapped* value) so that for example, this would be possible?...

```
Content{
  VStack{
    Item().padding(.bottom, Item.isTapped ? 20 : 0)
    Item().padding(.bottom, Item.isTapped ? 20 : 0)
    Item().padding(.bottom, Item.isTapped ? 20 : 0)
  }
}
```

edit: A key detail of note is that the number of Items would be generated dynamically by the user, so I can't for instance make a variable for each item

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as @State in the parent and pass it into the child as @Binding.

Comment: Are you sure that won't then affect ALL Items when the bool is toggled? I want to just affect the one that's been tapped (using an onTapGesture within the Item View to detect and toggle the bool)

Comment: You would need to declare 3 of them for your example. @State item1selected = false etc.

Comment: I updated the question with a clarification at the bottom mentioning that the number of Items being generated are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

First define a "Source of truth" Model

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

enum itemType{
  case itemTypeA
  case itemTypeB
  case itemTypeC
}

struct ItemModel: Identifiable  {
  var id: Int
  var type: itemType
  var isTapped: Bool = false
}

class ObserverModel: ObservableObject {
  var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  @Published var itemA: ItemModel = ItemModel(id: 1, type: .itemTypeA)
  @Published var itemB: ItemModel = ItemModel(id: 2, type: .itemTypeB)
  @Published var itemC: ItemModel = ItemModel(id: 3, type: .itemTypeC)

  func toggleItem(itemType: itemType) {
    switch itemType {
    case .itemTypeA:
      itemA.isTapped.toggle()
    case .itemTypeB:
      itemB.isTapped.toggle()
    case .itemTypeC:
      itemC.isTapped.toggle()
    }
  }
}
```

Your single ItemView should look like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var observer: ObserverModel
  @Binding var itemBinding: ItemModel
  @State private var toggleColor = Color.red

  var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
      .fill(toggleColor)
      .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
      .onTapGesture{
        self.observer.toggleItem(itemType: self.itemBinding.type)
        self.toggleColor = self.itemBinding.isTapped ? Color.green : Color.red

        print("Item Bool: \(self.itemBinding.isTapped)")
    }
  }
}

struct ItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ItemView(itemBinding: .constant(ItemModel(id: 1, type: .itemTypeA))).environmentObject(ObserverModel())
  }
}
```

Finally you put it all together:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemsView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var observer: ObserverModel

    var body: some View {
      HStack {
        ItemView(itemBinding: $observer.itemA)
        ItemView(itemBinding: $observer.itemB)
        ItemView(itemBinding: $observer.itemC)
      }
    }
}

struct ItemsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ItemsView().environmentObject(ObserverModel())
    }
}
```

I uploaded this to github: https://github.com/ppoh71/SwiftUIButtonTest
(Built with GM2)

And I would recommend this video about the data flow in SwiftUI.
this should explain everything: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/

[image]

Comment: Thanks this has been very helpful learning about observers! But one key thing I think I left out which as far as I know would throw a wrench in this solution is that the number of Items is dynamic, so I cant exactly repeat the following "@Published var itemA: ItemModel = ItemModel(id: 1, type: .itemTypeA)" because I dont know how manu Items will end up being made by the user. I've updated the question to mention the Items are generated dynamically, I'm sorry for not including it originally because you put a lot of effort into your solution